# Oracle module installation on Server 2008 node js: specified procedure could not be found

Tags: node.js, oracle

After I worked a lot with the oracle module on my notebook and a VM, I tried installing it on the server. 
The server runs Windows Server 2008, R2 x64. After many problems the installation works. Only a few warnings, no errors. Now i wanted to start my node js file. It works fine on my notebook, but not on the server. It shows the following error:

```
C:\Users\sgrzbielok\node>node httpstream.js

module.js:356
  Module._extensions[extension](this, filename);
                               ^
Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
C:\Users\sgrzbielok\node\node_modules\oracle\build\Release\oracle_bindings.node

    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sgrzbielok\node\node_modules\oracle\lib\orac
le.js:2:16)

    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Googled the error but could not find a solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today on a windows 2008 R2 x64 server when attempting to reinstall node-oracle.  It meant that oracle_bindings.node wasn't built correctly.  For some reason, node-gyp didn't download all of its dependencies when I installed it with `npm install -g node-gyp`.  Check the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\` directory of your working setup (i.e. the notebook and/or VM).  You should see node-gyp's dependencies: *.bin, fstream, glob, graceful-fs, etc.*  Either install all of those modules onto the 2008 server, one-by-one, or just copy all of the module folders to the same destination on the 2008 server.  I then uninstalled and reinstalled node-oracle and it worked.

If node-gyp doesn't seem to be the issue, make sure that your PATH variable has the Instant Client listed ahead of your actual Oracle path:

`Path=C:\instantclient_12_1\vc10;C:\instantclient_12_1\;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;%PATH%`

However, the path-order issue is more akin to the `"Error: The specified`**module**`could not be found."` message.